# How can I set default yaml values for Jekyll drafts?

Tags: jekyll

I'd like to preview my drafts in my templates, but the views depend on posts having a `category` assigned. I've tried setting the [front-matter defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults) for the `_drafts` folder, but this doesn't seem to work.

How can I have default frontmatter added to my drafts when I run `jekyll s -D`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
      type: "drafts"
    values:
      layout: "default"
```

**Edit**: Reading jekyll's it this is supposed to work but it doesn't because drafts are merged in `posts` collection. So when it comes to retrieve defaults only `type: posts` is applied and never `drafts`. [See Jekyll::Document](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/3.0-stable/lib/jekyll/document.rb#L34).

A trick it to put your drafts in /drafts/_drafts folder.
And to set your default like this :

```
-
  scope:
    path: "drafts"
  values:
    layout: "default"
```

The only drawback is that this will add a `draft` category to the `post.categories` array.

Comment: Tried it out just now.. doesn't seem to be working. Other than putting posts into a layout, is there a good way to debug this?

Comment: Fantastic --- the edit does it. For me, the added category doesn't matter, but I assume that people who use them could just manually exclude the "drafts" category?